# IIS Native Module - Websocket

Tags: c++, winapi, websocket, iis-10

I'm looking to implement a native websocket handler via a native module in IIS.  I'm finding the documentation around it to be pretty vague and missing a lot of details.

I've created a IIS Native module DLL and it is working.  I can keep it simple and just return a hello world html file with HTTP/200 response, and all is well.

However, I'm running into an issue when attempting to have it handle a websocket connection.  There was a blog post on microsoft's IIS blog site [here](https://blogs.iis.net/jennylaw/iis-and-websockets) which describes how to handle a websocket connection.  I've followed it and have tested and, yes, the connection is opened from a web browser, however I cannot read data from the socket in the native module, and the connection often appears to close in error on the client - after a random amount of time it seems.

The OnBeginRequest method of the module is:

```
REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_STATUS CKIIS::OnBeginRequest(IN IHttpContext* pHttpContext, IN IHttpEventProvider* pProvider) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pProvider);

    HRESULT hr;
    
    // I've only placed this here so I can attach a debugger.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    this->_context = pHttpContext;

    IHttpResponse* pHttpResponse = pHttpContext->GetResponse();

    if (pHttpResponse != NULL)
    {
        pHttpResponse->Clear();

        pHttpResponse->SetStatus(101, "Switching Protocols");
        pHttpResponse->SetHeader(
            HttpHeaderUpgrade, "websocket",
            (USHORT)strlen("websocket"), TRUE);
        pHttpResponse->SetHeader(
            HttpHeaderConnection, "Upgrade",
            (USHORT)strlen("Upgrade"), TRUE);
        DWORD cbSent = 0;
        BOOL fCompletionExpected = false;
        hr = pHttpResponse->Flush(false, true, &cbSent, &fCompletionExpected);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

        IHttpContext3* pHttpContext3;
        HttpGetExtendedInterface(this->_server, pHttpContext, &pHttpContext3);

        IWebSocketContext* cts = (IWebSocketContext*)pHttpContext3->GetNamedContextContainer()->GetNamedContext(L"websockets");
    
        char buffer[1024 * 100];
        DWORD sz = 1024 * 100;
        BOOL utf;
        BOOL finalfrag;
        BOOL conclose;
        DWORD clxc = 78;
        BOOL expected;

        // This method call returns E_NOTIMPL.  
        // The documentation does not even indicate this is an expected return of this.
        HRESULT res = cts->ReadFragment(
            &buffer,
            &sz,
            false,
            &utf,
            &finalfrag,
            &conclose,
            Compl,
            &clxc,
            &expected);

        // Start a thread to read/write from the websocket.
        this->_runner = thread(&CKIIS::RunWork, this);

        // Tell IIS to keep the connection pending...
        return RQ_NOTIFICATION_PENDING;
    }

    // Return processing to the pipeline.
    return RQ_NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE;
}

void CKIIS::RunWork() {

    IHttpContext3* pHttpContext3;
    HttpGetExtendedInterface(this->_server, this->_context, &pHttpContext3);

    IWebSocketContext* cts = (IWebSocketContext*)pHttpContext3->GetNamedContextContainer()->GetNamedContext(L"websockets");
    
    for (;;) {
        // Loop to read/write the socket... 
        
        // If I call cts->ReadFragment() or cts->WriteFragment() here
        // the method will return E_NOTIMPL too.

        /// Eventually break out of the loop.
    }

    try {
        //this->_context->IndicateCompletion(RQ_NOTIFICATION_FINISH_REQUEST);
        this->_context->PostCompletion(0);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e){
        const char* barf = e.what();
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Few questions:

- Why does ReadFragment/WriteFragment return E_NOTIMPL.  Both in the OnBeginRequest method, or if I attempt to do it in its own thread.
- Is using a new thread to handle the read/writing to the websocket the preferred pattern here?  Having a busy loop like that polling for data seems pretty wasteful, but I cannot see any way to register for notifications when data comes available from the client

Comment: What are you talking about?  I am attempting to *use* IIS's websocket module, not clone.  The interface is exposed exactly for my use case.

Comment: How did you register your module?  If you used APPCMD.EXE, do you remember exactly how you used it?  I'm trying to register my own module, and I'm having trouble getting it to run correctly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have this working now, you'll want to do a few things:

- In regards to your polling the sending/receiving question, I found that with polling the receiving that putting in a `Sleep(10)` would cause IIS to make the w3wp.exe process go Suspended, polling with a `Sleep(100)` alleviated this issue. I try to make it a habit to put a `Sleep()` in when I need to do polling of some other thread(s) with a while loop.
- `Read/WriteFragment` are giving you `E_NOTIMPL` because they are not implemented apparently, I tried them and I either got `E_NOTIMPL` or it simply hang the `w3wp.exe` process. I don't know where you get `DWORD cxlc = 78` because the completion expected is a `void*` that points to some `IHttpCompletionInfo*`, apparently... What I did instead was implement my own websocket messaging by reading `RFC 6455`. I'll leave that as an exercise to you because my crude implementation still needs some improvements such as properly chunking messages with taking into account the bytes of the header used for the payload and key sizes.
- Your response for the initial handshake needs to include the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header with the correct response key, which is the Base64 encoded SHA1 hash of the key as a string with `258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11` concatenated to the end of that string prior to hashing and encoding, see `RFC 6455`.
- I chose to use `OnExecuteRequestHandler` instead of `OnBeginRequest` and make a file format e.g. `*.chatsocket` that upgrades to a websocket. Ideally this would give me the ability to redirect the `stdin/stdout/stderr` of a console program to a websocket without writing a separate TCP server for each program when it could simply reside on the IIS server.
- However, this will hang until you kill the w3wp.exe process if you return `RQ_NOTIFICATION_PENDING` with `OnExecuteRequestHandler`, so what I did was implement a custom notification and run `pHttpContext->NotifyCustomNotification(m_pCustomProvider, &expected)` on each iteration. IIS hangs for whatever reason on `RQ_NOTIFICATION_PENDING` on an `OnExecuteRequestHandler` but not on `OnCustomRequestNotification`.
- Make sure to enable `IHttpContext3::EnableFullDuplex()` after the initial handshake and response `Flush` operation.
- Then to continue reading but don't rely on `request->GetRemainingBytes()` because it will continue to return 0.

I do something like this instead:

```
asyncReadLock.lock();
if (!isInAsyncRead) {
    isInAsyncRead = true;
    DWORD bytesReceived = 0;
    BOOL completionPending = false;
    HRESULT result = (*request)->ReadEntityBody(
        this->receiveBuffer,
        this->receiveBufferSize,
        true,
        &bytesReceived,
        &completionPending
    );
}
asyncReadLock.unlock();
```

Run `ReadEntityBody` but specify `fAsync` as true, and handle the asynchronous call like so:

```
REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_STATUS OnAsyncCompletion(
    IN IHttpContext* pHttpContext,
    IN DWORD dwNotification,
    IN BOOL fPostNotification,
    IN OUT IHttpEventProvider* pProvider,
    IN IHttpCompletionInfo* pCompletionInfo
)
{
    currentModule.asyncReadLock.lock();
    DWORD completedBytes = pCompletionInfo->GetCompletionBytes();
    HRESULT status = pCompletionInfo->GetCompletionStatus();
    if (completedBytes > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)completedBytes; i++) {
            this->currentModule.ReceiveQueue.push_back(this->currentModule.receiveBuffer[i]);
        }
    }
    this->currentModule.isInAsyncRead = false;
    currentModule.asyncReadLock.unlock();
    return RQ_NOTIFICATION_PENDING;
}
```

I keep a `std::deque<unsigned char> ReceiveQueue` that keeps any bytes that come in via `ReadEntityBody` and in my main loop I'll pass those along to create `WebSocketMessages` as needed instead of using `ReadFragment`.

In summation, I've got a file handler now for IIS for a format like `*.chatext` or `*.chatsocket` that turns it into a websocket all in IIS as a Native Module without running a separate TCP server so I get the benefits of IIS features like HTTPS without the need for having to go through ARR or URL Rewrites, I have things working the way I expected them to work in the first place. I use `ReadEntityBody` instead of `ReadFragment` to continue reading incoming data after the handshake with asynchronous reads. I use read polling with a `Sleep(100)` on each poll, I also implement my own timeout for a set number of seconds to ensure IIS closes connections properly.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: You use `pCompletionInfo->GetCompletionBytes()` to get the number of bytes received, but how do you know how many bytes are left to receive? If `this->receiveBufferSize` is not big enough then the data could potentially get split, then we have no way of knowing where a frame begins and ends. Did you solve this, or just create a large buffer determined to be enough?

Comment: @b.sullender you don't know how many bytes are left to receive, it'll go up to the buffer size (4k in my case), but for each iteration you're adding the bytes received to a queue of bytes to process as frames, and at the beginning of each frame you get the payload size if going by the Websocket protocol RFC 6455, therefore you should know what the size of each frame should be when queued, regardless of multiple packet splits. If you don't have enough bytes queued up to process the next websocket frame yet, then don't process the frame yet, is how I approach it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks for explaining the solution.